# how to use json_loads method in Python 3.4

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm new to python. I want a help because i'm facing a error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python project/weather.py", line 9, in 
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_string.read())
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read' in my code.. please anyone can help me
here is my code

```
    import urllib.request
    import json
    key = "[f4321da5d4b38454]"
    while 1:
       zip = input('for which ZIP code you like to see the weather? ')
       url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/' + key + '/geolookup/conditions/q/PA/' + zip + '.json'
       f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
      json_string = f.read()
      parsed_json = json.loads(json_string.read())
      city = parsed_json['location']['city']
      state = parsed_json['location']['state']
      weather = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather']
      temperature_string = parsed_json['current_observation']['temperature_string']
      feelslike_string = parsed_json['current_observation']['feelslike_string']
      print ('Weather in' + city + ',' + state + ': ' + weather.lower() + '. The temperature is ' + temperature_string + ' but it feels like ' + feelslike_string + '.')
      f.close()
```

Any type of help wil be appreciable.

Comment: `json_string` is `f.read()`, so what do you expect `json_string.read()` to do?

Comment: yes you are right. but i have removed json_string.read() method & insert only json_string but it still gives an error .
here it is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python project/weather.py", line 9, in <module>
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'